# Guarantees for kind of threads for ExecutorService instances

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java-threads

The various [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instances created by [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) of course have quite different behaviour.

If you try the example program below (and its variants) you should see that it only prints "false". Since the services using [daemon threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-) die when the main thread dies, this is of course to be expected. But I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere except in the source, so how can I be sure this won't change in the future?

And if I can't be sure if daemon threads will be used when I create ExecutorService instances like this, how should I create them in a way that guarantees the behaviour I want?

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class ExecutorsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // These use normal threads
        // ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        // ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        // These use daemon threads
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        // ExecutorService es = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();

        es.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not rely on undocumented features of specific JRE / JDK implementation

Comment: @hoaz: Exactly, that's the point of this question. Is this actually undocumented? And if so, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on undocumented features of specific JRE / JDK implementation.

If you want to make sure threads are daemons or have specific thread name, you can use ThreadFactory API to construct them:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads, ThreadFactory threadFactory)
```

For some reason there is no corresponded method in Executors API for `WorkStealingPool` which accepts `ThreadFactory`.